# Can't add data to existing collection in MongoDB Atlas with mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I made a MongoDB Atlas account and then I made a cluster with a database called "Cubicle" and a collection in it called "Cubes" and when I connect to my MongoDB database and publish some data, MongoDB Atlas creates a new database for me named "Test" and collection "Cubes", but I want to add data to the already existing database and collection.

This is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

const cubeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
type: String,
required: true
},
description: {
type: String,
required: true,
maxLength: 120
},
imageUrl: {
type: String,
required: true,
validate: function(){
return this.imageUrl.startsWith('http');
}
},
difficultyLevel: {
type: Number,
required: true,
min: 1,
max: 6
},
accessories: [
{
type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'Accessory'
}
]
});

const Cube = mongoose.model('Cube', cubeSchema);

module.exports = Cube;

And here is my code in cubeService:

```
exports.create = (cube) => Cube.create(cube);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would check your connection URI. Are you connecting to the proper DB in your cluster? I assume `/test` is a default database if you're not providing the connection URI explicitly.

Comment: mongodb+srv://.........:.........@cubicle.uccp0m2.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: Have you tried adding `cubicle` after slash like this `mongodb+srv://.........:.........@cubicle.uccp0m2.mongodb.net/cubicle?retryWrites=true&w=majority` ?

Comment: Yes, but I receive an error.

Comment: It works now, I have to delete already created db and then to write cubicle in conn string. Thanks a lot.